# disable or delete 'flutter_service_worker.js' in not a flutter server

Tags: flutter, dart

I just made a dart WAS project by `dart create my-server`

```dart
import 'dart:io';
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final server = await HttpServer.bind('localhost',8000);
  server.listen((request) {
    final response = request.response;
    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ok;
    response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.write('<h1>Hello, world</h1>');
    response.close();
  });
  print('Server running at http://localhost:8000');
}
```

but the word 'flutter' appeared

Dev Tools capture:

[image: Dev Tools capture]

I searched about that file,
but there are only things about flutter web

I dont think my project related to flutter
Why it appears in my source tab?
Is it a part of `dart:io` or `dart:http`?
If its not essential part of my project, I wanna disalbe or delete it